# The exception message is: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Code' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I am trying to visit a WCF service endpoint like xxx.svc. And I got this error:

```
The exception message is: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Code' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

I turned on the fusion log and got this:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = xxx\xxx
LOG: DisplayName = App_Code
 (Partial)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/myService/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\myService\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\myService\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
```

I don't have the App_Code folder in my web application. Why does it look for App_Code???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure it out after a good night sleep. I forget the precompiledApp.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you use an invalid reference or you are not referencing something you would like to use. The solution is to review your web.config and all references, searching for needed but missing references or invalid references.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just figure it out after a good night sleep. I forget the precompiledApp.config file. ...I want to remove my dummy brain.